# How can I search for all terms across two fields in Solr?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

All terms in the query should be present in the combined content of the fields. E.g. when I search for a combination of terms a document should be returned if:

- all terms are present in the 'description' field, the 'metadata' field or both fields
- or all terms are distributed over both fields (e.g. one term is present in the 'description' field and the two remaining terms are present in the 'metadata' field)

So `q.op=AND` but across two separate fields. How should I write my query?

What if I change the indexing to use a single multivalue field instead of two separate fields, does that make this scenario easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you can combine the two fields into a single multivalued field using [copyfield](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields).

```
<copyField source="metadata" dest="metadata_desc" />
<copyField source="descrition" dest="metadata_desc" />
```

The query can be formed with `q=metadata_desc:"some search"&q.op=AND`

With `q.op` the search for all the terms would be mandatory and should match for a document to be returned.  The default is `OR`.

This will take care of matching it in either of the fields as well as across the fields.